# How to make BeautifulSoup go to the specific webpage I want instead of a random one on the site?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn web scraping using BeautifulSoup by scraping UFC fight data off of the website Tapology. I have entered in the URL of a specific fight's webpage but every time I run the code it seems to jump to a new random fight on the page instead of this fight. Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/bouts/2093-ufc-76-the-dean-of-mean-keith-jardine-vs-chuck-the-iceman-liddell'
html_text = requests.get(url, timeout=5).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

fightstats = soup.find_all('td')
fightresult = soup.find_all('div', class_='boutResultHolder')
print(fightresult, fightstats)
```

Honestly I have no idea how it could be switching to other webpages when I have a very specific URL like the one I am using.

Comment: I just ran your code - and for me it seemed to navigate to the correct page. What happens when you navigate to that page using a browser? Any issues ?

Comment: Can you please share your invalid results? I think maybe the websites bans you for many requests.

Comment: They are probably protecting their information. Based on their privacy policy : `We automatically collect certain information, including information pertaining to your IP address, browser type, browser language, operating system, computer type (including mobile device type), access time and duration, landing page, and the pages you accessed during your visit, as well as any web pages and URLs you utilized to arrive on or depart from the Site. We collect and store this information when you use the Site, even if you have not created an account on the Site.`

Comment: @ParhamAlvani Printing the fightresult variable I can see that it is scraping pages for fights other than the one I am trying to scrape. Some of them are as follows: Timi Ogundipe defeats Angel Pacheco via 3 Round Decision, Dan Christison defeats Brad Imes via Submission at 3:37 of Round 3, and Oscar Delgado defeats Joe Johnson via KO/TKO at 1:35 of Round 1

Comment: @ScottC When I put in the URL in a browser it goes to the right page every time. When I run the code it seems to go to a random fights webpage. If it is the case that they are banning me from scraping the page I want, is there any way to get around this or do some websites just not allow webscraping?

Comment: you could perhaps use or implement proxies

Answer (score 0):

I got the same results (*"..every time I run the code it seems to jump to a new random fight..."*) when I tried your code. Like some of the comments suggested, it's probably in an effort to evade bots. Maybe the right set of headers could resolve it, but I'm not very good with making requests imitate un-automated browsers - so in situations like these, I sometimes use [`HTMLSession`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) (or cloudscraper or even ScrapingAnt, and finally selenium if none of the others work).

```py
# from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/bouts/2093-ufc-76-the-dean-of-mean-keith-jardine-vs-chuck-the-iceman-liddell'
req = HTMLSession().get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

fightstats = soup.find_all('td')
fightresult = soup.find_all('div', class_='boutResultHolder')
print('\n\n\n'.join('\n'.join( # remove some whitespaces from text for better readability
    ' '.join(w for w in t.text.split() if w) for t in f if t.text.strip()
) for f in [fightresult, fightstats]))
```

For me, that prints

```
Keith Jardine defeats Chuck Liddell via 3 Round Decision #30 Biggest Upset of All Time #97 Greatest Light Heavy MMA Fight of All Time


13-3-1
Pro Record At Fight
20-4-0
Climbed to 14-3
Record After Fight
Fell to 20-5
+290 (Moderate Underdog)
Betting Odds
-395 (Moderate Favorite)
United States
Nationality
United States
Albuquerque, New Mexico
Fighting out of
San Luis Obispo, California
31 years, 10 months, 3 weeks, 1 day
Age at Fight
37 years, 9 months, 5 days
204.5 lbs (92.8 kgs)
Weigh-In Result
205.5 lbs (93.2 kgs)
6'1" (186cm)
Height
6'2" (188cm)
76.0" (193cm)
Reach
76.5" (194cm)
Jackson Wink MMA
Gym
The Pit
Invicta FC 50
11.16.2022, 9:00 PM ET
Bellator 288
11.18.2022, 6:00 PM ET
ONE on Prime Video 4
11.18.2022, 7:00 PM ET
LFA 147
11.18.2022, 6:00 PM ET
ONE Championship 163
11.19.2022, 4:30 AM ET
UFC Fight Night
11.19.2022, 1:00 PM ET
Cage Warriors 147: Unplugg...
11.20.2022, 12:00 PM ET
PFL 10
11.25.2022, 5:30 PM ET
Jiří "Denisa" Procházka
Glover Teixeira
Jan Błachowicz
Magomed Ankalaev
Aleksandar "Rocket" Rakić
Anthony "Lionheart" Smith
Jamahal "Sweet Dreams" Hill
Nikita "The Miner" Krylov
```